# UBUNTU 17.04 Acer Aspire e15 Touchpad not working

Tags: touchpad, 17.04

I am new to Ubuntu. I've done a clean installation of Ubuntu 17.04, and the touchpad of my Aspire E15 does not work.

The result of the xinput command is:

```
xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYN1B7E:01 06CB:2970 Touchpad             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech M315/M235                        id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD WebCam                                 id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 17.02. Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Answer (score 1):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-i2c-hid.conf <<< "blacklist i2c_hid"
```

and reboot.